# Largura do container não diminui após quebra de linha

Tags: html, css

Tenho um container `id=container` onde são adicionados elementos dentro dele de forma dinâmica.

```css
#container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Ele começa com a largua pequena e vai aumentando conforme adiciono itens dentro dele.
O problema é que ao chegar na largura máxima e quebrar a linha, o container não diminui a largura para acompanhar os filhos, mas mantêm a largura máxima (vide foto abaixo).
Tem alguma propriedade que faria a largura do container se ajustar após a quebra de linha?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta fornecendo um [mcve] do problema e explicar como tentou resolver, e descrever o mais objetivamente possível qual foi a dificuldade encontrada. Ao editar, automaticamente sua pergunta é destacada para uma revisão e a comunidade reavalia os votos e o fechamento. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor entendimento da finalidade das perguntas e respostas do site.